# Exit button that can ask you "Do you want to close it"?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in java and I have a question for you do you know how I can create the button of exit? This button can ask me before I close the application "Do you want to close this application? or "Are you sure to close it?" I need to do it for my project and I need help. Pls send me some code.

Comment: "Pls send me some code." This is not how Stack Overflow operates. Please read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions that receive good answers. You should also read up on what topics are considered [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad, however, an AlertDialog is what you are looking for, this is the implementation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Search how create a dialog on Android.
Link ->  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=es-419

2.- In your view put a back button with onClickListener, insert showDialog created inside.

3.- Implement the override onBackPressed method, insert showDialogCreated inside.

Example onBackPressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    var dialog = CustomDialog.newInstance();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
    dialog.setOnClickListener((whichViewID, tag, args) => {
      // Your Logic 
      // If is pressed positive button call super.onBackPressed else dialog.dismiss()
    });
}
```